# How can I use ssh with AWS ssm sessions and multi profiles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

With the explosion of multi-account AWS configuration, and ssh being snuffed out in favor of session manager, I need ssh functionality and multi-profile ProxyCommand.

From [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html) it's simple enough. But I can see now way to add extra args to specify a profile. All I can think of is essentially concatenating the profile to the instanceid and creating dedicated commands.

**The question:**
How can I support multiple profiles using aws ssm when the proxycommand doesn't seem to offer me extra args?

Example that I would like: `ssh ec2-user@i-18274659f843 --profile dev`
Because the `i-*` doesn't indicate what account profile to use

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do, and what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to export. You can use it like this:
`AWS_PROFILE=bernard ssh ubuntu@i-xxxx`

The value of `AWS_PROFILE` will be valid only for this command and will save you from later issues with AWS commands, i.e. for other profiles.

In the same way you can set the region:
`AWS_REGION=us-east-1 AWS_PROFILE=bernard ssh ubuntu@i-xxxx`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the example below in your `ssh/config`, you can just define AWS_PROFILE environmental variable before connecting to the desired instance

```
host i-* mi-*
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

terminal:

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=bernard
$ ssh i-12345
```

Comment: That could work. I will give it a try - I see the logic. Have you tried this? Do you know it works?