# How to get AWS SSH to apply a --profile variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-cli

When doing ssh to an AWS instance we use the following and works, however, this only reads the default was profile.

```
ssh -i <File.pem> -L <Local_Port>:<Remote_Port> ubuntu@i-<HOST_Name> -N -v -v
```

.ssh/config

```
# SSH over Session Manager
host i-* mi-*
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

I can address this by manually added `--profile <Profile_Name>` to the `.ssh/config aws ssm start-session`.

.ssh/config

```
# SSH over Session Manager
host i-* mi-*
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --profile <Profile_Name> --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

How can I call this `--profile <Profile_Name>` as a variable in the SSH command and have it apply when it calls the ProxyCommand?

Comment: Dup as it was already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893323/how-can-i-use-ssh-with-aws-ssm-sessions-and-multi-profiles

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AWS_PROFILE=profile ssh ubuntu@i-xxxx`